# I can't access Facebook, Google and some other websites on my Firefox

Tags: windows, networking, firefox

My country and provider don't block major websites but Google, Yahoo, Facebook and others are blocked on my Firefox. They aren't blocked on my Chrome.

I already tried antiviruses (Avast and ESET NOD) and anti-spyware (MalwareBytes) — what now?

I don't want to use proxies, I want to solve the problem itself on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: OP figured it out (mentioned in a comment below), it was an IP6 issue. @Christian - Please answer your own question with what you did to fix your problem and how you figured it out. It will help future people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check proxy settings in firefox browser, and revise installed firefox addons and their settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are *not* using a proxy in your system settings and in Firefox's settings. Your LAN settings window should have "Use a proxy server for your LAN" unchecked. In Firefox, you should have "No proxy" selected in its connection settings.

Comment: there was no proxy. I just solved the problem after months, the cause of the problem was called ipv6

Comment: @Cristian Welcome to Super User. Remember to type your answer in the Answer box below. :)